# Numpy.Cov of a Large Nx3 Array Produces MemoryError

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, covariance, point-clouds

I have a large 2D array of size Nx3. This array contains point cloud data in (X,Y,Z) format. I am using Python in Ubuntu in a virtual environment to read data from a .ply file.

When I am trying to find the covariance of this array with *rowvar* set to *True* (meaning each row being considered a variable), I am getting ***MemoryError***.

I understand that this is creating a very large array, apparently too large for my 8 Gb allocated memory to handle. Without increasing memory allocation, is there a different way of getting around this issue? Are there different methods of calculating the covariance matrix elements so that the memory is not overloaded?

Comment: What is the value of `N`?

Comment: The value of N could be as large as 23000.

Comment: Please post your code. From my experience, 8Gb should be enough

Comment: The result will require about 4 Gb of memory.  Can you check how much memory is actually free before you compute the covariance matrix?  Also, what are you going to do with that 23000x23000 matrix once you have computed it?

Comment: What shape do you want the result to be? 3x3 or NxN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could chop it up in a loop and keep the upper triangle only.

```
import numpy as np

N = 23000
a = np.random.random((N, 3))
c = a - a.mean(axis=-1, keepdims=True)
out = np.empty((N*(N+1) // 2,))
def ravel_triu(i, j, n):
    i, j = np.where(i>j, np.broadcast_arrays(j, i), np.broadcast_arrays(i, j))
    return i*n - i*(i+1) // 2 + j
def unravel_triu(k, n):
    i = n - (0.5 + np.sqrt(n*(n+1) - 2*k - 1)).astype(int)
    return i, k - (i*n - i*(i+1) // 2)
ii, jj = np.ogrid[:N, :N]
for j in range(0, N, 500):
    out[ravel_triu(j, j, N):ravel_triu(min(N, j+500), min(N, j+500), N)] \
        = np.einsum(
            'i...k,...jk->ij', c[j:j+500], c[j:]) [ii[j:j+500] <= jj[:, j:]]
```

Obviously your covariances will be quite undersampled and the covariance matrix highly rank-defective...

Comment: Why does this help? You've still allocated the NxN matrix

Comment: @Eric It avoids the NxNx3 intermediate which on my system makes the difference between non-doable and just doable.

Comment: @Eric I see your point now, how silly of me. To save a little bit of face, I'll update it to use the upper triangle only.

Comment: @troymyname00 I've updated my A to only use a bit above half the memory. It stores the upper triangle only. I've included convenience functions which translate between 2d and compressed indices.

Comment: So to confirm, is there a `NxNx3` intermediate? I can see why there might be, but it seems like a sensible implementation wouldn't create one.

Comment: @Eric No, there doesn't appear to be one. At least, my computer can take the full `einsum` but chokes on `(c[:, None, :] * c [None, :, :]).sum(axis=-1)`.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Thanks for the suggestion.